# Multiple switches with the same parent link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**Sandbox** https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-hofstadter-ym4lo

I'm new to react and I'm trying to have the following routes; I'm using a switch in the `App` component

/authenticate
/panel/dashboard
/panel/accounts

In this case any routing to `/panel/` is loaded from the `Panel` component. I want to handle any further routing for `dashboard` and `accounts` here. However, what happens now is, when a user clicks to switch navigation from the `Panel` component the component does not update (the url does). Whenever I refresh the URL, ofcourse, it does render.

**Example**
https://gyazo.com/4b76250fd02a2b09859e90abc7386485

**Code**
App.jsx

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    redirect: null,
    errors: {},
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/panel" component={Panel} />

        <Route
          path="/authenticate"
          render={(props) => <Authenticate {...props} errors={this.state.errors} handleLogin={(event) => this.handleLogin(event)} />}
        />

        {this.state.redirect ? <Redirect to={this.state.redirect} /> : null}
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  {/* Left some functions out for clarity. */}
}

export default App;
```

Panel.jsx

```
class Panel extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="panel" className="page-wrapper">
        <Container className="page-container" fluid>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={2} className="column">
              <div className="list-group">
                <NavLink to="/panel/dashboard" exact className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" activeClassName="active">
                  Dashboard
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/panel/accounts" exact className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" activeClassName="active">
                  Accounts
                </NavLink>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={10} className="column">
              <Card className="w-100">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/panel/dashboard">
                    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/panel/accounts">
                    <h1>Accounts</h1>
                  </Route>
                </Switch>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Panel;
```

I'm having another switch in the `Panel` component so I do not have to rerender the sidebar, and can just load in the proper component depending on what route the user is (is there anything wrong with doing this, or is the better way in general).

**Summary**
So the problem is that the components are not loaded in when navigating to /panel and clicking on the navbar.

Edit: Excuse me for some of the things I had within the code. I like to be edgy when writing my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Panel component needs to receive the Router Props either you can use `withRouter` or pass on the Router Props from ProtectedRoute to the rendered component

```
class Panel extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="panel" className="page-wrapper">
        <Container className="page-container" fluid>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={2} className="column">
              <div className="list-group">
                <NavLink to="/panel/dashboard" exact className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" activeClassName="active">
                  Dashboard
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/panel/accounts" exact className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" activeClassName="active">
                  Accounts
                </NavLink>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={10} className="column">
              <Card className="w-100">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/panel/dashboard">
                    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/panel/accounts">
                    <h1>Accounts</h1>
                  </Route>
                </Switch>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Panel);
```

Comment: I added both withRouter to my App component and to my Panel component. However I am still left with the same problem. Also, could you clarify what "pass on the Router Props from ProtectedRoute to the rendered component" means?

Comment: Can you remove exact prop from NavLink and try it again. Because ifyou wrap PAnel component with withRouter it should work

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing here; https://gyazo.com/98222fd205e605eb7e3f24afd53c6f94

Comment: Ok, could you create a codesandbox demo with your issue. I will try and fix it

Comment: I will, give me a few.

Comment: I made one, does the link work?
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-hofstadter-ym4lo - You  still need to manually go to /panel.

Comment: I looked at your codesandbox. You haven't imported `Switch` correctly from the `react-router-dom` package. Fixing the import fixes the issue. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-breeze-qeijv?file=/src/pages/Panel.js)

Comment: Oh, wow, that's an entire day wasted on a few characters.. it works now. Thanks a lot!